# Swap arrays in linked list

Tags: arrays, c, visual-studio, linked-list, singly-linked-list

So, I have to swap data of two nodes.
Here is the function i created:

```
void swap(struct st* a, struct st* b)
{
    struct st* temp;

    temp->lname = a->lname; //lname is an array of chars
    a->lname = b->lname;
    b->lname = temp->lname;

    temp->marks = a->marks; //marks is an array of doubles
    a->marks = b->marks;
    b->marks = temp->marks;
}
```

> So i do not understand why an error occures.
> The error is following:  **E0137    expression must be a modifiable lvalue**

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to change where an array is when you do `a->lname = b->lname;`. That's not allowed. You would need to `strcpy` the string from one `struct st` to another. Also, `struct st* temp;` is an uninitialized pointer. It doesn't point at any allocated memory so the program has undefined behavior trying to use it.

Another option is to copy the whole `struct st` at once:

```
void swap(struct st* a, struct st* b)
{
    struct st temp = *a;  // initialize temp with *a
    *a = *b;
    *b = temp;

    // swap next pointers back
    b->next = a->next;
    a->next = temp->next;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This declaration

```
struct st* temp;
```

declares an uninitialized pointer with an indeterminate value. So dereferencing the pointer as

```
temp->lname = a->lname;
```

invokes undefined behavior.

Secondly arrays do not have the assignment operator. Arrays are non-modifiable lvalues. And this error message

> E0137 expression must be a modifiable lvalue

means that you are trying to assign one array to another.

If you need to swap data members of the structure `st` for two nodes then the function can look the following way

```
void swap(struct st* a, struct st* b)
{
    struct st temp = *a;
    *a = *b;
    *b = temp;

    struct st *p = a->next;
    a->next = b->next;
    b->next = p;
}
```